# Why do my prints always produce a magenta tint? Is there a more calculated approach I can take to my print prep?

Tags: print-production, color-conversion, color-profile, color-reproduction

I photograph and colour correct oil painting photographs

I shoot in Adobe RGB and print on a latex printer with the company's ICC profile (I don't know if I have to embed it into my photos or the print software, ONYX, converts it). The image is darker than my image. I realize I shouldn't be basing my corrections off the monitor but comparing sample to piece just makes it into guess work at this point. It's driving me insane because I know I've properly white balanced my photos and even calibrated a colour checker for my images. My boss assures me the latex printers are calibrated correctly but I seem to be constantly wrestling with magenta (most egregiously in my highlights) and darker overall tones in my prints compared to my image.

Why are my images constantly plagued by magenta? How can I use a more calculated approach to my print prep? Do I need to convert/embed anything into my images or does the print software take care of that for me?

I'm lost. Maybe I'm not good enough for this job.

Comment: Is your monitor calibrated and do you preview the print color?

Comment: Your title & question body appear unrelated. Anyway, welcome to the 'fun' world of colour matching. You say you are using a colour checker… but is your screen properly calibrated too? To truly match screen to print you would need not only a colorimeter but also a spectrophotometer. See https://www.xrite.com/blog/colorimeter-vs-spectrophotometer

Comment: Monitors are not calibrated. Director has no plans of spending anymore money on gear (had to fight tooth and nail for the tripod and colorchecker). @joojaa Are you refering to previewing the colour digitally or printing samples? Because I print 12x24' samples to compare.

Comment: If you can not calibrate your monitor then andy adjustmen you do is just guessing. A hardware calibrator is cheap compared tp several misprints. YOu can try to lend one for now.

Comment: I'd be looking for another job - one where management will support your endeavours, not make your task impossible then blame you.

Comment: @Tetsujin If I can somehow get these tools, what would the process look like. Is it as simple as WYISYG?

Comment: I agree with the other comments, but besides getting better equipment you can do some simple detective work. Try to make an image with neutral gray color swatches and print like you normally do. If these gray swatches have a magenta tone there is something wrong with the color conversion workflow or the printer's calibration.

Comment: @Wolff I can do that right now. Just tough getting my work done and solving the issue at the same time.

Comment: There are too many unknowns to properly help you. Do you print yourself in-house? If so, someone must know if you are supposed to convert to a certain profile or if the printer software is set up to properly convert from Adobe RGB. But no matter if you convert or not it's probably important that the profile is embedded. *Untagged* files might be misinterpret.

Comment: @Wolff No one seems to know if I should embed their profiles into my image but they gave me access to the folder containing all the ones my pieces would be printed on. I'm going to embed the profile next round of samples and we will see. In the mean time I'll print off the grey and see what happens.

Comment: Be aware that adobe rgb is very large in gamut. What you are reporting souns like something out of gamut could do for you... We sometimes wonder if we should on purpose print stuff badly so students would understand that working outside our  labs is not always as easy as students think. There is a lot of things we handle that you just dont generally get from elsewhere without paying big bucks.

Comment: @joojaa I think I need to go to the library. The more I learn the less I know in this endeavour.

Comment: Try this: Shoot your photos in sRGB, not Adobe RGB, and see if it makes any difference. Shooting in Adobe RGB can cause all sorts of problems with colours especially if you are not following a fully colour calibrated work flow (including both monitor and printer calibration).

Comment: I am wondering if your printer(s) are correctly calibrated. Did someone at your company create these printing profiles for each type of substrate? I've had issues using profiles designed for the printer and ended up using an X Rite spectrophotometer to scan the prints and create new profiles.

Comment: @BillyKerr I will be shooting in sRGB from now on. Adobe was a failed experiment on my end it seems.

Comment: @AndrewH These are HP provided.

Comment: Looking at it another way... "Everything I cook is burned. But the boss won't invest any any hardware to change the setting on the stove." -- Where's the problem???

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe I'm not good enough for this job.

Probably the ones not good enough are the printing company you choosed.

> My boss assures me the latex printers are calibrated correctly

Is your boss, your boss, or the boss of the printing company? **Any printer that wants to deliver a professional output must be calibrated**, any monitor must. And it must be calibrated for the specific conditions the work is facing.

Make a simple test. Prepare a grayscale gradient on RGB color mode and send a print. Drop any color profile embedded. You can also send another test using adobe 1998 profile.

If it turns magenta there is no doubt. The printer is NOT calibrated.

---

**What can you do?**

Make sure your own monitor is actually calibrated, and the only way to do it is... actually calibrating it.

You have two brands, Xrite and Data color, and several models to choose from.

- [www.xrite.com](http://www.xrite.com)
- [www.datacolor.com](http://www.datacolor.com)

Then:

1. Show the tests to the printing company. But to someone in charge, not the cashier.

The process of calibrating needs a series of print and measure cycles, but each correction must be installed on the computer managing the printer, so they can apply it. This is primordial on printers that primarily uses an RGB file. Most digital printers do this.

2. You could prepare an "inversed" curves to counter the exceed magenta, but if you try to make a professional workflow this is not the way to do it.
3. Change to a more serious provider that actually has the printer calibrated and tells the customers what profiles to use.